# Heroku not installing properly on Raspberry-Pi

Tags: heroku, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I'm using [this](https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/installations) guide to web development and I'm required to install some CLIs. I'm coding on a raspi v2 running stretch. When I try to install Heroku CLI I get an error:

Input:

```
wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

Output:

```
+ SUDO=
+ id -u
+ [ 1000 != 0 ]
+ SUDO=sudo
+ echo This script requires superuser access to install apt packages.
This script requires superuser access to install apt packages.
+ echo You will be prompted for your password by sudo.
You will be prompted for your password by sudo.
+ sudo -k
+ sudo sh
+ dpkg -s apt-transport-https
+ echo deb https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./
+ dpkg -s heroku-toolbelt
+ true
+ + apt-key add -
wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt/release.key
OK
+ apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch InRelease      
Hit:3 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ InRelease     
Hit:4 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x stretch InRelease
Hit:5 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
+ apt-get install -y heroku
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package heroku
```

What am I doing wrong? Is Heroku compatible with Raspbian? Is there a work-around? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently the 'install-ubunty.sh' requires super-user access. Execute it as `sudo ./install-ubuntu.sh`

Comment: @sevatitov Would the cli-assets.heroku... part stay then?

Comment: The `wget` command is still the same. Get familiar with the pipe syntax on the Unix command line. E.g. : http://www.linfo.org/pipes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question:

> Is Heroku compatible with Raspbian?

Answer: Yes it is.

---

They currently working on a cross-platform install method for the CLI with snap. But folks have gotten the CLI to install on arm via `npm` but they don't officially support it. Snap should be a great solution for arm users when it's ready. But at the moment, you could install the standalone heroku toolbelt for linux arm like it is described in [Standalone installation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli)

```sh
# Run this from your terminal.
# Replace OS with one of “linux”, “darwin”, “windows”, “freebsd”, “openbsd”
# Replace ARCH with one of “amd64”, “386” or “arm”
wget https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/heroku-OS-ARCH.tar.gz
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib /usr/local/bin
tar -xvzf heroku-OS-ARCH.tar.gz -C /usr/local/lib
ln -s /usr/local/lib/heroku/bin/heroku /usr/local/bin/heroku
# ensure that /usr/local/bin is in the PATH environment variable
```

Comment: run `tar` on `sudo` mood then. i.e `sudo tar -xvzf heroku-OS-ARCH.tar.gz -C /usr/local/lib`

Comment: When I ran the "tar" line, every line of output said "Cannot open: No such file or directory" //EDIT// Ah, ok, thanks a lot!